# A more haskellian way to write this recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I wrote a code to compute the coefficients of the quotient of two infinite series, using reduction, as follows:

```
main :: Int -> PInt
main 0 = 0
main n = cancel x3
    where
    x1 = someOtherFunction
    x2 = expression involving x1
    x3 = x2 - (foldr 
        (\y z -> z + (someOtherFunction y) * (main (n - y))) 0 [1..(n - 1)])
```

(I have defined a data called PInt, which is an instance of Num and Fractional, and there is an auxiliary function "cancel" to perform a reduction.) My problem is the expression in the fold in x3: it seems not very efficient, as it has to calculate every main k for lower values of k.

I am thinking maybe I can use an implementation such as

```
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

for fibonacci numbers to calculate the recursion above, which is more efficient. Unfortunately I have no clue as to where to start.

Thanks for any help in advance.

P.S. The code takes a significant amount of time to compute the value at 20, which behavior seems to imply the exponential growth of time?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask for reviews of code that's already working.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: (Perhaps you can simply [memoize](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization) `main`.)

Comment: @Mauris In fact I have used memo1, which I omit to show because it turned out not very useful in this case: there was not much difference. Or are you suggesting I use some sort of memo_n to recursively memorise it??

Comment: Two possible explanations: the coefficients grow in complexity so quickly as to outweigh the cost of recomputing earlier coefficients, or you did the memoization wrong (not hard to do).

Comment: @ReidBarton After I tried Daniel's answer, the code does generate results fast enough, so I think I might have "memorised" the function wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meat of the function looks like this:

```
main 0 = 0
main n = f [main n' | n' <- [0..n-1]]
```

You've told us a little bit about `f`, but not really enough to do much with `f` itself. Even so, as you say we can memoize some stuff by attacking the recursive calls:

```
mains = 0 : map f (inits mains)
main = (mains!!)
```

In fact, in your code, your specialization of `f` happens to never look at the head of the list it's provided (and you internalize this by computing `[1..n-1]` instead of `[0..n-1]`). We can push this concern through into `mains`, if we like, by:

```
mains = 0 : map (f' . drop 1) (inits mains)
-- corresponds to the specification:
-- main 0 = 0
-- main n = f' [main n' | n' <- [1..n-1]]
```

Though I think it may actually be cleaner to leave that to `f`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: this is the first time I heard of inits and its use. Thanks for this great answer then! :)